# How to find range of a rational function without using graph and inverse?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Specifically,
$$y= \frac{x-1}{x-4},\quad x\neq 4$$
I know how to find by inverse since domain of inverse is range of original function.

Comment: I just want to find domain and range . Dont think limit is necessary. Correct me if wrong

Comment: I think that we need the limits in general. If the function is continous everywhere, we might find the range without them.

Comment: This question is in my textbook(just started calculus). And i asked it here as it is written there.

Comment: Is your function $x-\frac{1}{x}-4$ or $\frac{x-1}{x-4}$ ?

Comment: The second makes the most sense, @Peter, because $x=4$ is explicitly excluded from the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $$y=\frac{x-1}{x-4}=1+\frac{3}{x-4}.$$ Therefore, $$x=4+\frac{3}{y-1}.$$ Can you figure out the range of the function? Can $y=1$?

Comment: Isnt this using the inverse method? Because x = inverse of function(y) which can be written as inverse of function(x)

Comment: Yes, you are right. The domain of the inverse function, i.e., all real numbers except 1, is the range of the original function.

Answer (score 0):

$y= \dfrac{x-1}{x-4}\iff y(x-4)=(x-1)\iff x(y-1)=4y-1\iff x =\dfrac{4y-1}{y-1}$

So $y\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{1\}$